# R split a formula including brackets

Tags: r, split, formula, brackets

I am currently writing a Package that estimates Stochastic Frontier Models with MLE or a Gibbs Sampler.
An enduser should be able to enter his formula like this:

sfm(formula = **y ~ x1 + ... + xk  + (z1 + ... + zr)**, data = ...) (K-x variables, r-z variables)

My problem:
I dont know how to properly split the formula into 2 parts.
The result after splitting should be: 
*1: "y ~ x1 + .. + xk*"
*2: "z1 + .. + zn"*

Thank you so much in advance.
Best

Comment: It doesnt have to be that exact result. something similar would be absolutely fine too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
library(stringr)
formula <- y ~ x1 + ... + xk + (z1 + ... + zr)
formula <- as.character(formula)
str_extract(formula, "(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))")[3]
[1] "z1 + ... + zr"

a <- str_extract(formula, "^.*?(?=\\s\\+\\s\\()")[3]
paste(formula[2],formula[1],a)
[1] "y ~ x1 + ... + xk"
```